# Using xargs to generate links

Tags: bash, sed, curl, xargs

I have a `file` that looks like this:

```
abc,123,x
xabc,345,xy
cabc,6234,ab
abgc,12,yo
jabc,9991,to
```

I need to generate a list of links:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com?param1=abc&param2=123&param3=x
http://www.mywebsite.com?param1=xabc&param2=345&param3=xy
```

...and so on.

How do I do this with `xargs`/`sed` or whatever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{print "http://www.mywebsite.com?param1="$1"&param2="$2"&param3="$3}' file
```

- `-F,`: set the delimiter to `,`
- `print`: print the text in the desired format (where `$1`, `$2` and `$3` represent the 3 fields of `file`).

---

The output:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com?param1=abc&param2=123&param3=x
http://www.mywebsite.com?param1=xabc&param2=345&param3=xy
http://www.mywebsite.com?param1=cabc&param2=6234&param3=ab
http://www.mywebsite.com?param1=abgc&param2=12&param3=yo
http://www.mywebsite.com?param1=jabc&param2=9991&param3=to
```

---

Now you can pipe that to `xargs` which calls `curl`:

```
awk ... | xargs curl
```

Or to `wget` which can read from stdin by itself:

```
awk ... | wget --input-file=-
```